# for iteration in self: what's in the list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

In the `cookielib.CookieJar` class, `__init__` declares just one object property: `self._cookies={}`.

In the `str` method, there is this statement:

```
for cookie in self: .....
```

What would the iterated object `cookie` be?

What would `cookie` be if there is also a, say, `self.x=0`, in `__init__`?

Comment: Can you please link the source code to the class name? It would be easier for people to look at the code.

Comment: The source code on my Windows PC is in `C:\Python27\Lib\cookielib.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cookielib.CookieJar` defines an [`__iter__`](http://nullege.com/codes/search/cookielib.CookieJar.__iter__) method, and this is called by `for cookie in self`.